# How to convert to a zero byte file?

Tags: unix, shell, command-line

HI,

in unix  there are number of files in my directory.
i want to change all the files to zero byte files.
is that possible on a single command line?

for example:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 sumanma  dev          434 Jan  8 14:36 pprbc_NL.cpp
-rw-r--r--   1 sumanma  dev          488 Jan  8 14:37 pprbc_TreeBuild.cpp
-rw-r--r--   1 sumanma  dev          783 Jan  8 14:37 pprbc_UPDwm.cpp
```

i want to change these to

```
-rw-r--r--   1 sumanma  dev          0 Jan  8 14:36 pprbc_NL.cpp
-rw-r--r--   1 sumanma  dev          0 Jan  8 14:37 pprbc_TreeBuild.cpp
-rw-r--r--   1 sumanma  dev          0 Jan  8 14:37 pprbc_UPDwm.cpp
```

I am using `tcsh`

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/90008/how-to-clear-the-contents-of-a-file-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can.

Try this

```
for i in *
do
 echo -n > $i
done
```

(Assuming bash here but the basic idea is the echo).

**Edit** : One liner (bash). You'll need the semicolons etc. which you won't need in the multiline version.

```
 for i in * ; do echo -n > $i ; done
```

**Edit**: If you're stuck using `tcsh`, you can always invoke bash to run a one liner like so

```
 bash -c 'for i in * ; do echo -n > $i ; done'
```

Comment: as i said i need on command line this is not so useful.
i can write the script but i want to know what is the command line trick for this.

Comment: Type that as a one liner into the command line and it will work as you want. You don't have to make it a script.

Comment: ` for i in test*fdef do echo -n >$i done
i: Undefined variable.
`

Comment: for i in *; do  echo -n > $i; done

definitely works in bash, just tested it. Do you use bash? did you miss the ; after * (or test*fdef in your case)?

Comment: `[28]> for i in test*fdef; do echo -n > $i; done;
for: Command not found.
i: Undefined variable.
done: Command not found.
`
i am having tcsh

Comment: Surely, you can adapt it to `tcsh`. I'm not familiar with that shell but the basic idea is to loop over your files and `echo -n` into them.
This is starting to sound like a *please solve my problem for me* question.

Comment: Not really your fault at all, but this won't work in tcsh. (Aha, you guys seem to have noticed.)

Comment: Just FYI, you *can* enter multi-line scripts at a bash prompt. If you type something that's not a one-liner (e.g. the first line of a 'for' statement), the prompt will change to a '>' and allow you to enter the rest of the lines. The multi-line script will be executed after you type the terminating token (done, fi, etc).

Comment: @Andrew, that's why I first suggested it but the OP I think wanted a "command line *trick*"

Answer (score 2):

I can't immediately think of an easy one-liner for tcsh.

Here is a three-liner:

```
foreach i (*)
  cat /dev/null > $i
end
```

You can type this in on the command line, i.e., it doesn't have to be a script. Unfortunately for one-liner purposes, and unlike the sh-series, the csh-derived shells parse the control structures by line, not by pipeline. This means that `foreach i (*); echo $i; end` won't work.

Of course, you could do a one-liner by switching shells for a line:

```
sh -c 'for i in *; do cat /dev/null > $i; done'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in *
do
   [ -f "$file" ] && >"$file"
done
```

Comment: This is a nice sh script but he is using a csh-derived shell, and this won't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

For one file you can use

```
>file.cpp
```

For more then one you need a for loop as already described from others. If there is a directory in the current directory, then you recive an error message.

```
for f in *;do >$f;done
```

to avoid this use

```
for f in *;do [ -f $f ] && >$f;done
```